# Including a class in another class

Tags: c++, class, templates, include, inclusion

So I'm trying to use the Node class that I just wrote in my LinkedList class but I'm getting the error that:

```
Symbol 'Node' could not be resolved
```

in the code below.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_

#include "Node.h"

template<class T>
class LinkedList {

    private:
        //Data Fields-----------------//
        Node<T> head;
        Node<T> tail;
};

#endif /* LINKEDLIST_H_ */
```

Node's declaration is below:

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_

template<class T>
class Node {
```

UPDATE:

So I still am having issues with my Node class being included in my LinkedList. But I discovered that by placing the two classes in one header file, I have no problems. So it must mean that the problem lies solely with the inclusion....which confuses me because that makes it seem like its some language based nuance that a beginner to C++ like me doesn't know about..

Comment: Can you try to encapsulate all of these in a namespace? OR Replace the first two lines in each header file with #pragma once.

Comment: I'm kind of new to C++ I wouldn't really know how to do that...could you explain?

Comment: which compiler do you use and which compiler flags are enabled?

Comment: the GCC compiler via MinGW. THe options I have are:

-E -P -v -dD "${plugin_state_location}/specs.cpp"

I did not set these, they were in eclipse by default

Comment: Does `Node.h` by chance include your `LinkedList.h`?

Comment: No it doesn't, Node doesn't have any inclusions actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you have the semicolon after #include "Node.h" that's the problem.
Edit: Things you can do to troubleshoot:

1. Inline the class definition
   i.e. replace the # include statement with the actual definition of the class (for testing only)
2. Check your header guards (the ones like # ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
   try renaming them or removing them altogether (again for testing only)

Comment: Have you tried inline-ing the included class definition instead of doing the #include?

Comment: Sure you can have an object as a member. I am asking you to only replace the incude statement with the actual definition of the class - for testing only.

Comment: ah, my mistake. let me give it a go

Yes that fixed it.....So I guess it's not including it correctly...somehow

Comment: any ideas as to what could be wrong with the include statement?

Answer (score 0):

So this just randomly started working for me...I don't know what the problem was but it works now... I'm using the CDT with eclipse, and it isn't the most stable thing for C++ development. SO my guess is that it has to do with that somehow....